# Magento 2.2.4 EE Upgrade Magento version fail, Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2-cloud

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2.2.4 EE using composer but, upgrade fail and and show error message  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. 
I have project in magento cloud.I follow Upgrade step from https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html

Please see attach screenshot.

[image]

Comment: There are so many sources of this error, this image shows lack of information, more details please?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a few things, but to start I would recommend running `composer self-update` to update to the latest version of Composer as the issue looks to be the version.

If that does not resolve it, please post the output of `composer --version` as well as your `composer.json`.